# PHP-MySQL function not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a function in PHP:

```
function doSQL($sql,$line)
{
    $resutl = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error on line: " . $line . "<br>SQL Query: " . $sql . "<br>Error: " . mysql_error());
    return $result;
}
```

This is for the sole purpose of minimizing the need to type endless MySQL queries.

I call it like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM airfields WHERE id LIKE '" . $_GET['id'] . "'";
$result = doSQL($sql,__LINE__);
```

But, it throws this error on all the calls:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in xxx\xxx\xxx\get_contacts.php on line xx
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A spelling checker in your editor? "$resutl" is clearly wrong.

Comment: wow... how'd I miss that... Thank you.

Okay, follow up question then: If I remove `$result` and just put `return mysql_query($sql)`, it doesn't do anything. The error is slightly different though. It says `expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`, why does that happen?

Comment: It doesn't make sense. Using `return $result`, it works. But using `return query`, it doesn't. I'm not changing the query.

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note, using your code as is will be very risky, security wise. Make sure you properly escape your get variables to SQL injection attacks.

Also, I would recommend using a better PHP database module, such as mysqli: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

It's easier to use and a lot safer.

Comment: Thanks, will keep this in mind! :)

Comment: I've quickly googled a proper way to do this and got this page. Will this suffice? http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/phpmysql-make-all-post-or-get-variables-safe-for-mysql-insert/

Comment: That will protect you from most SQL injections. But make sure you sanitize data inserted via INSERT before you output back to html to prevent Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks.

Comment: A simple method would be to use htmlentities to convert html-readable characters such as < and > to avoid someone injecting malicious code into your html output

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've got a LONG way to go regarding PHP/MySQL security (well, online security in general). Do you perhaps have a good resource that I can read regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

```
function db_connect($server,$username,$pass,$database)
{
   $result = new mysqli($server, $username, $pass, $database); 
   if ($result->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $result->connect_errno . ') ' . $result->connect_error);
   }

return $result;
}
```

Comment: I connect to the database before the statements in my question.